# repository of UDFs or stored procedures

Tags: mysql, postgresql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I am looking for open source repositories of stored procedures or UDFs (targeted database doesn't matter). One example is http://www.mysqludf.org/ . I am wondering if folks know of similar repositories? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure of any central repository. You will probably find multiple sites with some isolated repositories such as http://orafce.projects.pgfoundry.org/. I really like this idea though and it should be put in place.

Comment: Agree that it would be useful to have some repository of categorized, tagged sql functions/code snippets. Recently I've used [pgNumerics](http://pgnumerics.projects.pgfoundry.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two

- older http://pgfoundry.org/
- and newer http://pgxn.org/

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such "repository" for PostgreSQL. The idea seems strange to me - after all - all functions/procedures work on some data, so they are very specific in what they do.

There is a [Snippets category](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Category%3aSnippets) in PostgreSQL wiki, though.

Comment: I think there are cases where function logic is standard code and could be shared. Though you are correct many, probably most tend to be very specific.  I'm thinking things like logging frameworks and timing functions stuff that all disciplines and business could make use of.

Comment: See Pavel's answer for larger chunks like that. PostgreSQL has it's EXTENSION feature in more recent versions.